# Open payment gateway with cUrl

Tags: php, curl, symfony1, payment-gateway

I'm trying to access a payment gateway. In the example of the bank does with a simple html FORM but I want to do it by cURL. 
My problem is when I try to access to payment gateway does not see css (gateway stylesheets) and javascript fail. 
Is there any way to avoid these errors?

```
    $url = sfConfig::get('app_tpv_url');

    $dsOrder = $this->getDSOrder($order);
    $dsAmount = (float)$order->getPriceWithShipping() * 100;
    $dsCurrency = sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_currency');
    $dsMerchantCode = sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_code');
    $dsName = sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_name');
    $dsLanguage = ($this->getUser()->getCulture() == 'es') ? 1 : 2;
    $dsTerminal = sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_terminal');
    $dsSignature = sfConfig::get('app_tpv_merchant_signature');
    $dsTransactionType = 0;

    sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers('Url');
    $dsUrl = url_for('cart_ipn', array('sf_culture' => $this->getUser()->getCulture(),), true);

    $dsStringResult = $dsAmount + $dsOrder + $dsMerchantCode + $dsCurrency + $dsTransactionType + $dsSignature;
    $digest = sha1($dsStringResult);

    $options = array(
        'Ds_Merchant_Amount' => $dsAmount,
        'Ds_Merchant_Currency' => $dsCurrency,
        'Ds_Merchant_Order' => $dsOrder,
        'Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode' => $dsMerchantCode,
        'Ds_Merchant_MerchantName' => $dsName,
        'Ds_Merchant_ConsumerLanguage' => $dsLanguage,
        'Ds_Merchant_Terminal' => $dsTerminal,
        'Ds_Merchant_MerchantSignature' => $digest,
        'DS_Merchant_TransactionType' => $dsTransactionType,
        'Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL' => $dsUrl
    );

    $fields_string = '';
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->getContext()->getRequest()->getHttpHeader('User-Agent'));

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: If youre going to do it this way you should use the API version of the gateway and build your own forms and cart and then use cURL or sfWebBrowser to send/recieve data. Otherwise you should direct offsite or use an iframe which is how the Gateway setup youre using now is meant to be used. Even if you sort out the issues with the URL translation youre probably going to have larger technical problems actually getting to work functionally.